# How to get wildcard class (?.getClass())

Tags: java, class, wildcard

I have such class:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<NodeRpcResponseList<?>> {
```

How can I get class of "?" in order to use this class inside CustomDeserializer?

Comment: There is no general way to do it. It depends upon what meaning that type variable has in the class in which it is defined. Consider a `List<?>`: how would you work that out? Maybe you could look at one/some elements, but what if that's a subtype of the "actual" type? What if the list is empty? If you *actually* need to know the type, there is probably something deficient in the design.

Comment: @AndyTurner That only applies to lists, with classes, that information is embedded directly inside the class file (this can be proven bij trying to use the subclass and seeing that it knows its generic types on the generic methods)

Comment: @Ferrybig then I await your answer with interest.

Comment: Thanks for comments. 
This is exackly what I have. NodeRpcResponseList contains List<?>. If there is no general method, it looks I have problem :(

Class NodeRpcResponseList needs to be created from Json, so I don't have access to instance of this class. Hmmm. have no idea what to do.

Comment: @Ferrybig are you referring to the case of `JsonDeserializer<NodeRpcResponseList<SomeSpecificClass>>`? Sure, you can get `SomeSpecificClass` in that case; but there is no type to get if it is a wildcard.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was indeed referring to that example, just discovered that my logic didn't work

Comment: The problem is I even don't have idea how to go around this

Comment: @CD is there any way to change it to `public class CustomDeserializer<E> implements JsonDeserializer<NodeRpcResponseList<E>>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner

Yes! I can do something like this:

public class CustomDeserializer<E extends NodeRpcResponse> implements JsonDeserializer<NodeRpcResponseList<E>> {